# org-table-iterate not working for tables with named columns

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have the following two tables:

```
| ! | slope | intercept |  xval | yval |
|---+-------+-----------+-------+------|
|   |   1.2 |        -5 |   1.4 |      |
|   |   2.4 |         2 |    -5 |      |
|   |  -5.6 |        -3 |   2.2 |      |
|   |  -0.2 |         4 | 2.718 |      |
|   |   .56 |      3.14 |  -0.5 |      |
#+TBLFM: $5=$2*$4+$3


|   | slope | intercept |  xval | yval |
|---+-------+-----------+-------+------|
|   |   1.2 |        -5 |   1.4 |      |
|   |   2.4 |         2 |    -5 |      |
|   |  -5.6 |        -3 |   2.2 |      |
|   |  -0.2 |         4 | 2.718 |      |
|   |   .56 |      3.14 |  -0.5 |      |
#+TBLFM: $5=$2*$4+$3
```

The only difference between these tables is that the first has named columns while the second doesn't. For both tables, I can calculate values in the last column one at a time by doing `M-x org-table-recalculate` or `C-c *`, but iteratively updating the table using `M-x org-table-iterate` or `C-u C-u C-c *` only works for the second table. For the first table, if I run `org-table-iterate`, I get the message "Table was already stable." Is this a bug, or am I not understanding how named columns are supposed to work?

I am running Org 9.4.6 and Emacs 27.2 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation (`C-h i g(org)Advanced Features`) says:

> ```
>  Important: Please note that for these special tables, recalculating
> the table with ‘C-u C-c *’ only affects rows that are marked ‘#’ or
> ‘*’, and fields that have a formula assigned to the field itself.
> The column formulas are not applied in rows with empty first field.
> ```

So e.g. this works:

```
| ! | slope | intercept |  xval |   yval |
|---+-------+-----------+-------+--------|
| * |   1.2 |        -5 |   1.4 |  -3.32 |
| * |   2.4 |         2 |    -5 |   -10. |
| * |  -5.6 |        -3 |   2.2 | -15.32 |
| * |  -0.2 |         4 | 2.718 | 3.4564 |
| * |   .56 |      3.14 |  -0.5 |   2.86 |
#+TBLFM: $5=$2*$4+$3
```